# Concatenate multiple list

Tags: scala, collections

I would like to know how to concatenate several list using a loop.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
object MyObj {
  var objs = Set (
    MyObj("MyObj1", anotherObjList),
    MyObj("MyObj2", anotherObjList)
  )

  val list = List.empty[AnotherObj]
  def findAll = for (obj <- objs) List.concat(list, obj.anotherObjList)
}
```

I would like the function findAll to concatenate lists from object of the set objs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
objs.flatMap(_.anotherObjList)
```

It doesn't use a `for`, but that's probably the most concise and readable way to do it in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`

Something like this:

```
objs.reduce((a,b) => a.anotherObjList ++ b.anotherObjList)
```

Or if the `Set` can be empty, use `foldLeft`:

```
objs.foldLeft(List.empty[AnotherObj],(a,b) => a.anotherObjList ++ b.anotherObjList)
```

Comment: this won't compile. `a` is a `List` not a `MyObj`

Comment: Why would `a` be a List? `objs` is a `Set` of `MyObjs`s.

Comment: I had tried the reduce way, it was not working.  Error is type mismatch; found: List[AnotherObj], required MyObj

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you are using a `val` `list` which cannot be reassigned.  When you do `List.concat(list, obj.anotherObjList)` you are creating a new list that concats the empty `list` to the current `obj`'s `anotherObjList`, but the *result* is never used, so `list` will still be empty after the execution of the for-loop.

If you really need to use a imperative for-loop, either use an immutable collection and assign it to a `var` which can be reassigned from the for-loop's body or use a mutable collection:

```
object MyObj {
  var objs = Set(
    MyObj("MyObj1", anotherObjList),
    MyObj("MyObj1", anotherObjList),
  )

  def findAllLoop1 = {
    var list = List.empty
    for (obj <- objs) list = list ++ obj.anotherObjList
    list
  }

  def findAllLoop2 = {
    val buf = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]() // replace Int with your actual type of elements
    for (obj <- objs) buf ++= obj.anotherObjList
  }
}
```

But If you don't have to use a imperative loop for some reason, I would strongly suggest to use a functional alternative:

```
object MyObj {
  var objs = Set(
    MyObj("MyObj1", anotherObjList),
    MyObj("MyObj1", anotherObjList),
  )

  def findAll = 
    objs.flatMap(_.anotherObjList) // if Set as return type is okay

  def findAll: List[Int] = 
    objs.flatMap(_.anotherObjList)(collection.breakOut)  // if elements are of type Int and you want to get a List at the end, not a Set
}
```